# How to change particular column entries in a mysql table when uploading data from csv file?

Tags: mysql, csv

I upload data into a mysql table from csv file in a standard way like this:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name;
load data local infile '/path/to/file/file_name.csv' into table table_name
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n'
(id, name, type, deleted);
```

All 'deleted' column entries in csv file has either 'current' or 'deleted' value.

**Question:** When csv data is being loaded into table, I want to put current date in table for all those corresponding 'deleted' entries in csv file. And null for 'current' entries. How can I do this?

**Example:** csv file:

```
id_1, name_1, type_1, current
id_2, name_1, type_2, deleted
id_3, name_3, type_3, current
```

Table after loading this data should look like this:

```
id_1, name_1, type_1, null
id_2, name_1, type_2, 2010-05-10
id_3, name_3, type_3, null
```

**Edit** Probably, I could run another separate query after loading csv file. Wondering if it could be done in same query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SET clause in [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) syntax:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
INTO TABLE t1
(column1, column2)
SET column3 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using another query to change those deleted entries is quite simple. I'm going with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just load the CSV file into an array and then iterate through it?  Or just iterate through the file itself?

Then you would just update/add the date to each record in your table as necessary (if field[2] == "deleted" or something like that).